# Pandoc filter mimicking default MathML conversion

Tags: haskell, latex, pandoc, mathml

I am writing a [Pandoc JSON filter](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html#json-filters) in Haskell that should transform display LaTeX math to SVG with an external application, whereas inline LaTeX math should be transformed to MathML by [`pandoc`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) internally.

The first SVG bit is working fine; it is the MathML bit that should mimic standard `pandoc` behaviour that is giving me problems.

Browsing Hackage, I found [the `texMathToMathML` code example](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/texmath-0.9/docs/Text-TeXMath.html) (see below). This function returns `Either String Element`.

However, what I need is a function `tex2mml` (see below) returning an `IO String`.
**What needs to be added to the definition of `tex2mml` to achieve this?**

```
tex2mml latex = texMathToMathML DisplayInline latex
```

I am doing this on (X)Ubuntu LTS 16.04 with the following `pandoc 1.16.0.2` packages installed:

```
$ sudo apt install pandoc libghc-pandoc-prof
```

Here is an excerpt of what I got so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env runhaskell

import Text.Pandoc.JSON
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Text.TeXMath (writeMathML, readTeX, DisplayType( DisplayInline ) )
import Text.XML.Light (Element)


texMathToMathML :: DisplayType -> String -> Either String Element
texMathToMathML dt s = writeMathML dt <$> readTeX s


tex2mml :: String -> IO String
tex2mml latex = texMathToMathML DisplayInline latex


main :: IO ()
main = toJSONFilter tex2math
  where tex2math (Math (DisplayMath) latex) = do
          svg <- tex2svg latex
          return (Math (DisplayMath) (svg))

        tex2math (Math (InlineMath) latex) = do
          mml <- tex2mml latex
          return (Math (InlineMath) (mml))

        tex2math other = return other
```

Please, bear with me, as I am an absolute Haskell beginner.
Any suggestions for code improvement are more than welcome!

Comment: "it is the MathML bit that should mimic standard pandoc behaviour that is giving me problems." --> Why don't you leave it as it is and let Pandoc handle it after your filter has run?

Comment: @SergioCorreia Because, I run `pandoc` with `--jsmath` instead of `--mathml` to generate the SVG using MathJax.

Comment: @SergioCorreia I double checked. Indeed, `pandoc` performs its [math conversion](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#math) _prior_ to exposing its [`ToJSONFilter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-types-1.16.1.1/docs/Text-Pandoc-JSON.html). As far as I know, below solution is the only way of getting there.

Comment: **EDIT:** A completely new, more modern Lua filter solution to this problem can be found [**HERE**](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/math2svg#math2svg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admittedly I'm not familiar with Pandoc and the problem domain but if correctly understood the purpose of `tex2mml` function then I believe this should achieve what you want:

```hs
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Text.Pandoc.JSON
import Text.TeXMath
       (writeMathML, readTeX, DisplayType(DisplayInline))
import Text.XML.Light (Element,showElement)

texMathToMathML :: DisplayType -> String -> Either String Element
texMathToMathML dt s = writeMathML dt <$> readTeX s

tex2mml :: String -> String
tex2mml latex = either id showElement (texMathToMathML DisplayInline latex)

-- actual definition of tex2svg goes here
tex2svg = undefined

main :: IO ()
main = toJSONFilter tex2math
  where
    tex2math :: Inline -> IO Inline
    tex2math (Math DisplayMath latex) = do
      svg <- tex2svg latex
      return (Math DisplayMath svg)
    tex2math (Math InlineMath latex) = return (Math InlineMath (tex2mml latex))
    tex2math other = return other
```

I'm using `either` function to scrutinise the result of the conversion function `texMathToMathML` - in case of failure the error is returned as is (`id`), in case of success `showElement` function is used to convert `Element` into its XML string representation.

This could also be rewritten using pattern matching if you find that clearer:

```hs
tex2mml :: String -> String
tex2mml latex = case texMathToMathML DisplayInline latex of
  Left err -> err
  Right xml -> showElement xml
```

As the computation is pure it doesn't need to be embedded in IO monad, and the result can be passed straight into the `Math` constructor.

There are also other functions in [Text.XML.Light.Output](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-1.3.14/docs/Text-XML-Light-Output.html) module if you wish to pretty print the XML string or wish to include XML document header in the output.

Comment: Exquisite answer with an excellent explanation! I learnt a lot from it.